# How can a shell script determine if a file is binary or text?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

Have a situation where I need a shell or bash script to determine if a file is binary or not.  The issue here is that the linux environment does not have `file` available and the `grep` version is from busybox which doesn't support `-I`.  I found a `perl` method (the perl version is old supports -e but not -E)  of it working but it's slow.  Does anyone have a faster method of determining if a file is binary?  TIA!!

```
#!/bin/sh

is_text_file() { 
  # grep -qI '.' "$1"   ### busy box grep doesn't support
  perl -e 'exit((-B $ARGV[0])?1:0);' "$1"  ### works but is slow
}

do_test_text_file_on_dir() {
  for f in "$1"/*; do
    [ -f "$f" ] || continue
    if is_text_file "$f"; then
      echo "$f" is not a binary file
    fi
  done
}

do_test_text_file_on_dir ~/testdir
```

Comment: hum, 2-3 ms on my shared machine.

Comment: You wouldn't want to use `-E` anyway; it's not forward compatible. It's for one-shot scripts.

Comment: Why not just drop the shell script and do it directly in a perl script?  That would save you the startup overhead from calling perl on each file.

Comment: *"the perl version is old supports `-e` but not `-E`"* Why not just tell us the version of Perl you're using (`perl -v`). That would be much more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid the time it takes to repeatedly load `perl` by doing all the work in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

for (@ARGV) {
   stat($_)
      or warn("Can't stat \"$_\": $!\n"), next;

   -f _ && !-B _
      or next;

   print("\"$_\" isn't a binary file\n");
}
```

Usage:

```
do_test_text_file_on_dir ~/testdir/*
```

---

Note: `!-B _` is equivalent to `-T _` except for empty files.